# Normal Distribution- Finding Expectations

Tags: statistics

Let X have a normal distribution with mean μ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find $E[X^3]$ (in terms
of μ and $\sigma^2$).

Im pretty sure that $μ= E[X]$ so to find $E[X^3]$ would i just split it up into $E[X*X^2]$ since i know $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$ can be found from the variance formula?

Comment: Your split up will not work. This because $X$ and $X^2$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $U$ has *standard* normal distribution then $\mathbb EU^3=0$.

This can be proved on base of symmetry (also $-U$ will have standard normal distribution so that $\mathbb EU^3=\mathbb E(-U)^3=-\mathbb EU^3$, and this implies $\mathbb EU^3=0$).

Observe that: $$U:=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$ has standard normal distribution.

**Edit**:

> $$\mathbb{E}X^{3}=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma U+\mu\right)^{3}=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma^{3}U^{3}+3\sigma^{2}\mu U^{2}+3\sigma\mu^{2}U+\mu^{3}\right)$$$$=\sigma^{3}\mathbb{E}U^{3}+3\sigma^{2}\mu\mathbb{E}U^{2}+3\sigma\mu^{2}\mathbb{E}U+\mu^{3}=\cdots$$

Comment: would that just mean that $E[X^3]$ would also just be 0 then?

Comment: No. $\mathbb EU^3=0$ and you can make use of the equality mentioned in my answer to find $\mathbb EX^3$.

Comment: Note that you can write $X=\sigma U+\mu$. Wright out $X^3$ and calculate expectation

Comment: so $E[X^3]=(σU+μ)^3$? Then i would just substitute back out the U for $(X-μ)/σ$? Sorry if this seems elementary to you, I am just struggling a bit in this class and trying to wrap my head around this topic before my final in a couple weeks.

Comment: If you cannot resist then see my edit.